# SonarQube API: projects with key that includes string

Tags: sonarqube

According to the [documentation](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/components) of `api/components/search`, parameter `q`:

> Limit search to component names or component keys that contain the supplied string.

Unfortunately, the statement is true only for names, searching with a key requires complete string. Is there any other possibility to search for projects using only a substring of a key?

Tried in 6.3.1 and 6.4, both versions do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for components by *partial keys* is currently not supported.

The code that controls the search results of this query is this snippet in [`ComponentMapper.xml`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-db-dao/src/main/resources/org/sonar/db/component/ComponentMapper.xml#L274):

```
  <if test="query.nameOrKeyQuery!=null">
    and (
      p.kee = #{query.nameOrKeyQuery,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
      or
      upper(p.name) like #{query.nameOrKeyUpperLikeQuery,jdbcType=VARCHAR} escape '/'
    )
  </if>
```

Here, `nameOrKey` is the value of the `q` parameter,
managed by [`ComponentQuery`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-db-dao/src/main/java/org/sonar/db/component/ComponentQuery.java).
In the above snippet you can see that the value is used either to *match exactly* the project key, or to *match partially* the project name.

Comment: In my opinion you should change the service description - it's misleading.

Comment: @ArturMalinowski the fix of the documentation will be part of an upcoming release ([here's the commit](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/pull/2453/commits/740d9dfb7397a36b0845c06a80c479584d7e071f))

Comment: Any chance that searching by partial keys will be supported?